# SQL How to stop cummulative sum when the value is positive (+)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to find a solution to create a cumulative sum with some logic, I have data like this:

[image]

We must add Column **Net** with Condition:

- first row, sum AR and ADV Column
- next row is sum with the result of first row so on
- stop cumulative sum when the result is positive +

Expected result is:

[image]

Comment: please do not post image, use the sample data and expected result as formatted text. Also include any attempted query

Comment: I don't understand your logic from your result table, please give more examples and details.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Window Functions - however you will need to take care in your `ORDER` clause in the function and ensure that your data is ordered in a definable way.

For your example, I have specified the order to be by `customer_no DESC` first of all and then by `number ASC`

The condition is then whether the Net value from the previous row is negative and if so add the current row's values to it.  I use `ISNULL(xxx, 0)` to account of the first row that doesn't have a `LAG` value.

```
SELECT number, customer_no, invoice_no, due_date, AR, ADV, 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(LAG (AR + ADV) OVER (ORDER BY customer_no DESC, number ASC), 0)  < 0 
        THEN AR + ADV + ISNULL(LAG (AR + ADV) OVER (ORDER BY customer_no DESC, number ASC), 0) 
        ELSE AR + ADV 
    END as Net
FROM CumulativeSum
```

Comment: Hi thnk u for your response, but when i try you suggestion it's doesn't work, the error message is "'LAG' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have and what compatibility level for your database?

Comment: this is my sql server version:
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1) (KB3182545) - 13.0.4001.0 (X64) 
 Oct 28 2016 18:17:30 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: LAG is available in your version of SQL Server, so not sure why it says it is not recognised.  Can you post the query that you have run to generate the error please - it may be a typo - and also the output of ```SELECT compatibility_level  
FROM sys.databases WHERE name = '<YOUR DATABASE NAME>';```